# I cant install the driver of intel 3165 in ubuntu20.04 correctly

Tags: 20.04

My kernel is generic 5.8.0-48, and because of my mistake, my wifi can't work.

When i type `lshw -C`, there is no logical name and the description doesn't display the driver for the network controller card.

Comment: The correct driver is *iwlwifi* which is installed by default. If it is not working, there is something else wrong. Let's find out. Please run: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` As the output may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: thank you,after i ran the command，it shows that：`modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)`.It seems

Comment: May we also see: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic | grep Status` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: After i ran the command `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic | grep Status` it shows  `Status: deinstall ok config-files` ,but when i type the command `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` ,there is no output.IS the system lose some moudles should be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Please get a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic 
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: Intel 3165 wifi does not work on jammy new install. I've tried the purge of the backport iwlwifi module but that didn't help. I followed the instructions on another post to give diagnostics. They are at https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/6tgVfYkmFj/

Comment: @JohnRose Please start your own new question.

Comment: My own new question is at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436632/intel-3165-wifi-does-not-work-on-jammy