# Intel 3165 wifi does not work on jammy

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

Intel 3165 wifi does not work on jammy new install. Ubuntu's Network Manager sees the router but never manages to connect to it.
I've tried the purge of the backport iwlwifi module but that didn't help. I followed the instructions on another post to give diagnostics. They are at https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/6tgVfYkmFj/

Some more info:

```
admin@Server:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 3165 
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81) Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010] 
admin@Server:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no
1: hci1: Bluetooth Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no 
2: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no –
```

Not dual boot. BTW Computer is an old Intel NUC.
I have tried installing linux-modules-iwlwifi-generic package using Synaptic (which installed linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0.52-generic, 5.15.0.52 being my kernel's version) but that gave "W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root, as file '/root/.synaptic/tmp//tmp_cl' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied) so I uninstalled those 2 packages).
I've just tried 'sudo apt install linux-modules-iwlwifi-generic" and that worked Ok. I rebooted, disconnected Ethernet & turned wifi on. But still get 'SSID connecting' which never finishes and no wifi.
If it is a kernel bug, how do I fix it?
I've also tried using https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html and copied the 3165 files to lib/firmware (including the copying of the 7265 files to equivalent 3165 files). That didn't work and I've since deleted them.
I haven't put in any rules into the firewall. I have turned the Firewall on to reject Incoming. My laptop has no wifi problems. My main PC has no problems using Ethernet.
I've reported this on Launchpad as bug 1993890.
I've tried a suggestion from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2480193 but after rebooting that didn't get the wifi working:
echo 'options iwlwifi power_save=0 uapsd_disable=0' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/wifihacks.conf
echo 'options iwlmvm power_scheme=1' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/wifihacks.conf
I've corrected that suggestion:
I've tried the solution for the 7265 chip at
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207409
i.e. using sudo, create a file /etc/modprobe.d/wifihacks
admin@Server:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/wifihacks.conf
options iwlwifi swcrypt=0
options iwlwifi power_save=0
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
options iwlwifi uapsd_disable=1
followed by a reboot
But that didn't work
Today's update of the linux-firmware package for Jammy did not make wifi work.

Comment: Is it a dual boot?

Comment: No. BTW Computer is an old Intel NUC

Comment: Some more info:
admin@Server:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 3165
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010]
admin@Server:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
1: hci1: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Ubuntu's Network Manager sees the router but never manages to connect to it.

Comment: Please do not use comments to add info to the question. Edit the question. Comments are for those trying to help you to ask for more info.

Comment: It is a kernel bug.

Comment: There can be other reasons too. E.g. your router has problems with dhcp, has some firewall restrictions that don't allow to connect, etc. The log shows a kernel problem. You can't fic it easily. You can report it to Launchpad and try another kernel. This device used to work with Linux very well for me. But I didn't test it with the latest Ubuntu kernels.